# HIVE : No result display

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using `cloudera-quickstart-vm 5.4.2` and `hadoop 2.7.1`.
I am running HIVE and have a csv file called hospital and mortality.
As you see the following code, the TABLE of mortality and the VIEW of dead_events are generated, but no result comes up by some reasons.  What would be the reason in this case?

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dead_events;
CREATE VIEW dead_events 
AS
SELECT patient_id, event_id, time FROM hospital WHERE patient_id = "%88%" OR patient_id = "%777%";

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details of how the table is created and loaded ?

Comment: Could you share the table DDL too

Comment: I added what you asked. Thanks.